# Exam Question : Using a 74163, implement the following counting sequence

Tags: digital-logic

During a past paper this question was given
**Using a 74163, implement the following counting sequence**

[image: seq]

Professor also added his own solution can be seen here :
[image: sol]

Can anybody explain to me thoroughly how can i reach the same answer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The shown solution seems to implement the counting sequence 5>6>7>8>9>10>11>5. But the loaded value is 3 or 7.

Comment: No, anyone wold make Your homework. Show us Your efforts and point the exact problem which stopped You.

Comment: Practical answer: You don't. A small microcontroller will likely be cheaper than the discrete components required to implement this, and will be more flexible too.

Answer (score 1):

You need logic with 4 inputs (QA...QD) that produces 5 outputs: when LD should be asserted and what 4 values should be loaded.

Some input values should never be encountered, so we can treat the outputs for those values as don't-cares.

Make a truth table, then minimize the logic (maybe using Karnaugh maps), and you should get a solution.